# Hyper-V DNS Forwarding

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, dns, hyper-v

I just installed Fedora 27 on a VM running on Hyper-V on a Windows 10 host and things are mostly running smoothly. The only missing piece so far is proper DNS resolution from within the VM.

I can successfully `ping` sites in the open Internet by IP address, but addressing them by their DNS name fails.

The VM identifies both the default route and the DNS server in the IP address of the host machine in the private network.

### Question

How can I make the host machine forward DNS queries from the VM to its own DNS servers?

#### Note

Using a public DNS server (e.g. Google's `8.8.8.8`) would *partly* solve my issue, as I'm on a company's private network and I'd like to seamlessly access it as I were working from the host machine.

Comment: I'd love to know how I can improve the question, since it received a downvote. :)

Comment: Can you reach the DNS server from the VM? Can you try if a direct query such as `dig +short @<ip-of-dns-server> www.google.com` work? If you want, you can try to clarify this more: "The VM identifies both the default route and the DNS server in the IP address of the host machine in the private network.". Ciao!